# Filebeat monitoring metrics not visible in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I am ingesting events from PubSub using Filebeat and send them to ES for indexing/vizualization. I noticed that under a particular high test load - not all events get to ES. So I'm trying to debug the pipeline - trying to figure out where the drop is happening.

I am hoping that I could get some insight into what is going on in the Filebeat by monitoring Filebeat itself and sending the metrics to the same ES cluster (hosted on elastic.io).

So I did:

-- enabled XPack monitoring in Elastic.io cluster as following:
[image]

-- enabled monitoring in the filebeat.yaml:

```
monitoring.enabled: true
monitoring.elasticsearch:
   
  api_key: ${ES_API_KEY}
```

having the elastic output configured as following:

```
# ---------------------------- Elasticsearch Output ----------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  enabled: true
  index: "ibc-parsed-logs"
  parameters.pipeline: "geoip-info"
  hosts: ${ES_HOSTS}

  # Authentication credentials - either API key or username/password.
  api_key: ${ES_API_KEY}
```

According to the Elastic docs - if I use an elasticsearch output - then the cluster ID/ auth/credentials will be determined from the above output config...

I also enabled logging of the monitoring metrics:

```
logging.metrics.enabled: true
```

When I run Filebeat with this configuration, I see that monitoring metrics are indeed collected - I see lots of logs like:

```
2022-09-30T01:58:49.765Z    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:192  Total metrics   {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cgroup":{"cpu":{"cfs":{"period":{"us":100000},"quota":{"us":0}},"id":"/","stats":{"periods":0,"throttled":{"ns":0,"periods":0}}},"cpuacct":{"id":"/","total":{"ns":1609969280422}},"memory":{"id":"/","mem":{"limit":{"bytes":9223372036854771712},"usage":{"bytes":59994112}}}},"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":950350,"time":{"ms":950351}},"total":{"ticks":1608520,"time":{"ms":1608525},"value":1608520},"user":{"ticks":658170,"time":{"ms":658174}}},"handles":{"limit":{"hard":1048576,"soft":1048576},"open":9},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"2f0fb51b-0dc7-4ea6-97ea-d9f07f7a9dd6","uptime":{"ms":15354077},"version":"7.15.0"},"memstats":{"gc_next":27183328,"memory_alloc":25632752,"memory_sys":77874184,"memory_total":51893040880,"rss":132669440},"runtime":{"goroutines":19}},"filebeat":{"events":{"active":0,"added":3095135,"done":3095135},"harvester":{"closed":0,"open_files":0,"running":0,"skipped":0,"started":0},"input":{"log":{"files":{"renamed":0,"truncated":0}},"netflow":{"flows":0,"packets":{"dropped":0,"received":0}}}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0,"starts":0,"stops":0},"reloads":0,"scans":0},"output":{"events":{"acked":3055775,"active":100,"batches":62013,"dropped":0,"duplicates":39360,"failed":0,"toomany":0,"total":3095235},"read":{"bytes":61600055,"errors":3},"type":"elasticsearch","write":{"bytes":3728037960,"errors":0}},"pipeline":{"clients":0,"events":{"active":0,"dropped":0,"failed":0,"filtered":0,"published":3095135,"retry":350,"total":3095135},"queue":{"acked":3095135,"max_events":4096}}},"registrar":{"states":{"cleanup":0,"current":0,"update":0},"writes":{"fail":0,"success":0,"total":0}},"system":{"cpu":{"cores":8},"load":{"1":0,"15":0,"5":0,"norm":{"1":0,"15":0,"5":0}}}}}}
```

However, when I go to the **ES cluster -> Observability -> Metrics -> Inventory**
I only see this message: "*Looks like you don't have any metrics indices.*" - and no metrics whatsoever - nothing in Kibana, no indexes with any metrics ...

Why are not metrics sent/displayed to ES? Did I miss some other configuration settings?

Thank you!
Marina

UPDATE 1: per suggestions in the answers below - I have enabled DEBUG logging for all categories - and can see a lot of additional info int he filebeat logs. From what I see - see excerpt below - Fielbeat indeed connects to the ES fine and is sending the metrics data to ES. But when I go to ES - no indices exist with any metric data. Theonly indices I see are those for my real data/events I'm collecting form pubsub, and some APM-related indices.

Full log: https://controlc.com/8021ff33

Snippet:

```html
2022-10-04T14:25:32.917Z    DEBUG   [esclientleg]   transport/logging.go:41 Completed dialing successfully  {"network": "tcp", "address": "XXX.us-east4.gcp.elastic-cloud.com:443"}
2022-10-04T14:25:32.945Z    DEBUG   [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:272   Ping status code: 200
2022-10-04T14:25:32.946Z    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:273   Attempting to connect to Elasticsearch version 7.15.0
2022-10-04T14:25:32.947Z    DEBUG   [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:328   GET https://XXX.us-east4.gcp.elastic-cloud.com:443/_xpack?filter_path=features.monitoring.enabled  <nil>
2022-10-04T14:25:32.982Z    DEBUG   [monitoring]    elasticsearch/client.go:101 XPack monitoring is enabled
2022-10-04T14:25:32.983Z    INFO    [monitoring]    elasticsearch/elasticsearch.go:244  Successfully connected to X-Pack Monitoring endpoint.
2022-10-04T14:25:32.984Z    DEBUG   [monitoring]    elasticsearch/elasticsearch.go:250  Finish monitoring endpoint init loop.
2022-10-04T14:25:32.984Z    INFO    [monitoring]    elasticsearch/elasticsearch.go:258  Start monitoring state metrics snapshot loop with period 1m0s.
2022-10-04T14:25:32.984Z    INFO    [monitoring]    elasticsearch/elasticsearch.go:258  Start monitoring stats metrics snapshot loop with period 10s.
2022-10-04T14:25:41.061Z    DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:139  Run input
2022-10-04T14:25:42.959Z    DEBUG   [monitoring]    processing/processors.go:203    Publish event: {
  "@timestamp": "2022-10-04T14:25:42.950Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "7.15.0",
    "type": "beats_stats",
    "interval_ms": 10000,
    "params": {
      "interval": "10s"
    }
  },
  "beat": {
    "type": "filebeat",
    "version": "7.15.0",
    "name": "9975cbe98075",
    "host": "9975cbe98075",
    "uuid": "08e8a88e-e214-4d48-a65c-d5b5226776a5"
  },
  "metrics": {
    "system": {
      "cpu": {
        "cores": 8
      },
      "load": {
        "1": 0.04,
        "5": 0.01,
        "15": 0,
        "norm": {
          "1": 0.005,
          "5": 0.0013,
          "15": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "beat": {
      "cgroup": {
        "cpuacct": {
          "id": "/",
          "total": {
            "ns": 596922278
          }
        },
        "memory": {
          "id": "/",
          "mem": {
            "limit": {
              "bytes": 9223372036854771712
            },
            "usage": {
              "bytes": 46735360
            }
          }
        },
        "cpu": {
          "stats": {
            "periods": 0,
            "throttled": {
              "ns": 0,
              "periods": 0
            }
          },
          "id": "/",
          "cfs": {
            "period": {
              "us": 100000
            },
            "quota": {
              "us": 0
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "handles": {
        "open": 20,
        "limit": {
          "hard": 1048576,
          "soft": 1048576
        }
      },
      "info": {
        "uptime": {
          "ms": 12033
        },
        "ephemeral_id": "3dac65ba-ee80-4333-8eeb-e46106b369c8",
        "version": "7.15.0"
      },
      "memstats": {
        "memory_alloc": 13034112,
        "memory_sys": 76104712,
        "gc_next": 21276432,
        "rss": 116137984,
        "memory_total": 64822632
      },
      "cpu": {
        "total": {
          "time": {
            "ms": 549
          },
          "value": 540,
          "ticks": 540
        },
        "user": {
          "time": {
            "ms": 323
          },
          "ticks": 320
        },
        "system": {
          "ticks": 220,
          "time": {
            "ms": 226
          }
        }
      },
      "runtime": {
        "goroutines": 71
      }
    },
    "registrar": {
      "states": {
        "current": 0,
        "update": 0,
        "cleanup": 0
      },
      "writes": {
        "success": 0,
        "total": 0,
        "fail": 0
      }
    },
    "filebeat": {
      "harvester": {
        "started": 0,
        "closed": 0,
        "running": 0,
        "open_files": 0,
        "skipped": 0
      },
      "input": {
        "netflow": {
          "packets": {
            "dropped": 0,
            "received": 0
          },
          "flows": 0
        },
        "log": {
          "files": {
            "renamed": 0,
            "truncated": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "events": {
        "done": 0,
        "active": 0,
        "added": 0
      }
    },
    "libbeat": {
      "output": {
        "read": {
          "bytes": 0,
          "errors": 0
        },
        "type": "elasticsearch",
        "events": {
          "batches": 0,
          "total": 0,
          "acked": 0,
          "failed": 0,
          "dropped": 0,
          "duplicates": 0,
          "active": 0,
          "toomany": 0
        },
        "write": {
          "errors": 0,
          "bytes": 0
        }
      },
      "pipeline": {
        "clients": 1,
        "events": {
          "active": 0,
          "total": 0,
          "filtered": 0,
          "published": 0,
          "failed": 0,
          "dropped": 0,
          "retry": 0
        },
        "queue": {
          "acked": 0,
          "max_events": 4096
        }
      },
      "config": {
        "scans": 0,
        "reloads": 0,
        "module": {
          "starts": 0,
          "stops": 0,
          "running": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
2022-10-04T14:25:42.964Z    INFO    [publisher_pipeline_output] pipeline/output.go:143  Connecting to backoff(monitoring(https://XXX.us-east4.gcp.elastic-cloud.com:443))
2022-10-04T14:25:42.964Z    DEBUG   [monitoring]    elasticsearch/client.go:66  Monitoring client: connect.
2022-10-04T14:25:42.965Z    DEBUG   [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:249   ES Ping(url=https://XXX.us-east4.gcp.elastic-cloud.com:443)
2022-10-04T14:25:42.964Z    INFO    [monitoring]    pipeline/retry.go:219   retryer: send unwait signal to consumer
2022-10-04T14:25:42.966Z    INFO    [monitoring]    pipeline/retry.go:223     done
2022-10-04T14:25:43.015Z    DEBUG   [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:272   Ping status code: 200
2022-10-04T14:25:43.016Z    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:273   Attempting to connect to Elasticsearch version 7.15.0
2022-10-04T14:25:43.017Z    DEBUG   [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:328   GET https://XXX.us-east4.gcp.elastic-cloud.com:443/_xpack?filter_path=features.monitoring.enabled  <nil>
2022-10-04T14:25:43.205Z    DEBUG   [monitoring]    elasticsearch/client.go:101 XPack monitoring is enabled
2022-10-04T14:25:43.207Z    INFO    [publisher_pipeline_output] pipeline/output.go:151  Connection to backoff(monitoring(https://XXX.us-east4.gcp.elastic-cloud.com:443)) established
2022-10-04T14:25:43.239Z    DEBUG   [monitoring]    memqueue/ackloop.go:160 ackloop: receive ack [0: 0, 1]
```

UPDATE 2: 10/06/2022:
After further struggles with getting the actual ES logs (which is not that simple on hosted ES clusters at elastic.io!!) - I finally was able to access them and noticed many of the following WARNings:

```
16:32:50.998
elasticsearch.server
[elasticsearch.server][WARN] Authentication to realm found failed - Password authentication failed for ec-local-beats-monitor
```

I'm not sure who this user might be: "ec-local-beats-monitor" ?? and where it is configured/set - definitely not in my filebeat.yml config for the Filebeat process...

Could this be related to the issue with loosing/ not indexing Filebeat metrics data into ES?

Comment: about the 2nd update. It seems you have a custom realm in your `elasticsearch.yml` named `found` and a user `ec-local-beats-monitor` failed to be auth via password.

Indeed from the settings you have on filebeat it does not seems to be related.

BUT which user own the api key ?

By the way if investigating those logs further is of interest I suggest looking into [audit logs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enable-audit-logging.html) ^^

Comment: Well I just checked, although API keys are linked to a user. They are not tied to its current roles. ei `user_1` create `api_key_1`, `user_1` get's deleted, `api_key_1` is still valid.

And error message from failed auth using api key looks like `Authentication using apikey failed - api key has been invalidated`

Comment: thanks, Paulo! I have posted this question on the Elastic forum as well: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-monitoring-metrics-not-visible-in-elasticsearch/315596/10 and per their suggestion - opened a case with Elastic support. Will update with the solution if we get one :)

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

I think they are multiple question in your post.

1. How to investigate dropped messages ?
2. How to access monitoring data of filebeat ?

I may have missed it, but posting the stack version you are running is always welcome.

## Solutions (maybe )

### 1. Dropped messages

Here are some ideas.

- Do you maybe have a [drop processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/drop-event.html)
- Check the filebeat logs for errors on processor
- Check [ingest pipeline for errors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/node-stats-api.html#pipeline-stats) ?

### 2. Monitoring

As [per the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/8.4/monitoring-data.html) you should find it under **stack monitoring**

Comment: Thank you, Paulo, for trying to help! Actually, I did not ask help for #1 - why messages are dropped - as I don't yet have enough information to speculate - this is why I am trying to get metrics from Filebeat collected. As for #2 - yes, I went to Kibana to see the Stack monitoring - but it is empty - so I started looking around more and realized that there are no monitoring indices - which are, AFAIK, what Kibana woudl use for metrics visualization. So the problem is that the metrics are not collected/sent from Filebeat somehow - and the question is "why"?

Comment: To solve #1 I feel logs are more interesting than metrics. As for #2 I am surprised  I am not sure I know how to help. The config looks perfect. Maybe in the logs of Elasticsearch you may have some clue ?

Comment: well there are no errors in the logs .... so I was trying to see if some other information could be gleaned from the Filebeat metrics - like over-loaded channels, or something like that - it's very hard to debug Filebeat as it is mostly a black box :(

Comment: You could make it [spout more logs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-logging.html)

Comment: I just enabled DEBUG logging for all categories - see an update in my post .... Seems liek the metrics are collected /sent to ES - but ES just ignores them

Comment: Very surprising indeed it seems the event is sent, have you had the time to check the logs on elasticsearch by any chance ?

Comment: it's the hosted elasticsearch on elastic.co - I don't think I can access their logs :(

Comment: Yes you can, do you have access to the dashboard `cloud.elastic.co` ? if so you should have on your deployment, metrics and logs where you should be able to browse some

Comment: it was not easy to get to the ES server logs on elastic.io :) - had to get my permissions elevated a few times - but finally I managed to - and I've added some findings to my post under the UPDATE2 section

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the log level to get more insight into the logs.

To get filebeat metrics,  Kibana -> Management -> Saved Objects and remove everything default related to beats and try rerunning it. Most default index templates are not configured correctly and It can lead to metrics not available on kibana.

Comment: thank you for suggestions - I have enabled debug logging - see an update in my post. Also, in ES/Kibana - it does not seem like a problem with mappings... no indices with any metrics data exist at all... Filebeat is pushing metrics events into ES - you can see that in the logs - but they seem to be just ignored by ES for some reason....